# Checking two different username and password combinations with while loop in C

Tags: c

Hey guys Im a C newbie and Im trying to create a program which asks the user to input a username and password until they get one of the two allowed combinations (usnm "user1" and pw "2020" or usnm "u" and pw "2020c").The problem is that the while loop doesn't stop even after inserting a correct combination and I'm not sure if it's a logic or syntax error on my part

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

char username[6];
char password[6];

printf("give username\n");
scanf("%s",&username);
printf("give password\n");
scanf("%s", &password);

while (strcmp(username, "user1") != 0 && strcmp(password, "2020") != 0
    || strcmp(username, "u") !=0 && strcmp(password, "2020c") != 0)
{
printf("give username\n");
scanf("%s",&username);
printf("give password\n");
scanf("%s", &password);
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calculate `strcmp(username, "user1") != 0 && strcmp(password, "2020") != 0
    || strcmp(username, "u") !=0 && strcmp(password, "2020c") != 0` in your head, and tell me whether you got true or false, and how you got that.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&username);` -> `scanf("%s",username);` - but read the manual page and amends the `%s` to prevent buffer overruns. Ditto with password

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...) and of your compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Look for inspiration in existing programs on [github](https://github.com/)

Comment: You might want to read up on the return value of [strcmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), namely that it returns 0 when the strings are *equal*

Comment: Rather than repeating code, use a `do`/`while` loop.

Comment: @user253751 is right. You are looping `while` _((we don't match the first set of credentials) or (we don't match the 2nd set of credentials))_. It is not possible to match both at once, obviously, so this condition is always true, so you loop forever. Rewrite to loop `while` _(we don't ((match the 1st set of credentials) or (match the 2nd set)))_. The other correct point about that comment was that doing the logic yourself with a pencil and paper, or stepping through all the comparisons using a debugger, would show this.

Comment: @underscore_d thank you so much for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

I think your Boolean logic is wrong. Should be more like this:

```
username[0] = '\0';
password[0] = '\0';

while (!(strcmp(username, "user1") == 0 && strcmp(password, "2020") == 0) &&
      (!(strcmp(username, "u") == 0 && strcmp(password, "2020c") == 0));
{
    printf("give username\n");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("give password\n");
    scanf("%s", password);
}
```

Comment: Please fix the `scanf` as well.

Comment: Might even modify the `%s` to prevent buffer over runs. i.e. `%5s`

Answer (score 0):

Using while loop in this way is not an efficient way to do what you want. Also you haven't included string.h which is required for strcmp function. Let's make it simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

char username[6];
char password[6];
bool valid = false;

while(!valid) {
    printf("give username\n");
    scanf("%s",&username);
    printf("give password\n");
    scanf("%s", &password);
    if( strcmp(username, "user1") == 0 && strcmp(password, "2020") == 0 ) {
        valid = true;
    }
    else if( strcmp(username, "u") == 0 && strcmp(password, "2020c") == 0 ) {
        valid = true;
    }
    else {
        valid = false;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```